# Translating "wings" (of a stage)

Tags: translation

Is there a set phrase for this term? It seems to me that an acceptable translation would be 舞台左右侧, but that seems rather long.

在中文里面，这词有一个约定俗成的翻译吗？我觉得”舞台左右侧“这翻译还行，但还是有点长。

Comment: 两侧 is short for 左右侧

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see online dictionaries, e.g. **iciba**: wing   in the wings
1In the stage wings, unseen by the audience. 在观众看不到的舞台**两侧**  bkrs:舞台**两则** 舞台左侧 舞台右侧

Answer (score 0):

侧面 is what you are looking for.

If you want to be more specific, you can write 舞台的侧面。